# Php code to store the document on particular folder

Tags: php

I need to create a page with 2 combobox in php - in the first combobox, if I select an item , then the second combobox should display the relevant items.

**Example:** If i select USA in the first combobox , the second combox has to display the cities in usa . If I select UK , the second combobox has to display the cities in UK. Now i have to upload a document and have to store this document in a folder in my local drive according to the item selected in combobox .

**Example:** If I select USA and California, the document has to store this in a folder named USA and the subfolder California.

How do I do it in PHP?

Comment: post what have you done so far

Comment: SO is a place to ask for help with specific coding problems, not a place to request tutorials. Try Google, there are plenty tutorials that explain this. Search for example: "jquery dependent dropdown"

Answer (score 0):

The question was not quite clear There 2 task:

1) You need to create page with combo boxed of countries and get data of states according to the selection.

2) According to selection of combo boxes you need to create folders/sub-folders and move uploaded files to that folder.

I feel that you were facing problem in creating nested directory structure then you can use

```
$path = $countryName.'/'.$stateName;
bool mkdir ( $path , 0777 , false );
```

may this help you...